# How can I plot an impulse series within a square wave?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a repeated impulse of 1 millisecond (ms) within a signal of 61 Hz (16ms).

My current code is:

```
Plot[{.5 (1 + SquareWave[ 61.03 t]),
ConditionalExpression[.5 (1 + SquareWave[1000 t]), t < .001]},
{t, 0, .032}, ExclusionsStyle -> Dotted, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005], Orange}]
```

The plot looks like this:

[image]

The problem is now, that I want to start the next impulse at the beginning of the next blue impulse. So it should look like this:

[image]

What do I have to change in my code in order to get such a behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generalize `squareWave` a bit:

```
squareWave[x_, range : {min_, max_} : {-1, 1}, duty_: 1/2] := (min + max)/
   2 + (min - max)/2 SquareWave[x/2] SquareWave[(x - duty)/2]

Show[Plot[squareWave[x/16, {0, 1}], {x, 0, 32}, ExclusionsStyle -> Dotted, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick],
 Plot[squareWave[x/16, {0, 1}, 1/16], {x, 0, 32}, ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Orange],
 AxesLabel -> {"t, ms"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot[{
  0.5 (1 + SquareWave[61.03 t]),
  ConditionalExpression[.5 (1 + SquareWave[1000 t]),
   0 < t < 0.001 || 0.0159 < t < 0.0166]},
 {t, 0, .032},
 ExclusionsStyle -> Dotted,
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005], Orange}]
```

[image]